# mysqli_fetch_array does not save complete dropdown data

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

I made a form where a user can select different options from a dropdown field. The selected option should be saved inside the database in another table. So here is what I did:

Get data from database for dropdown list:

```
include 'inc/database.php';
// Get all Schulen from Database
$get_schulname3 = "SELECT schulname FROM schule";
$result_get_schulname3 = mysqli_query($connect, $get_schulname3);
```

Display dropdown field on website:

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Schule:</label>
   <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
     <?php  while ($get_schulname3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result_get_schulname3, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
        echo "<select name='schule-lehrer' class='form-control'>Dropdown</option>";
        while($r3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result_get_schulname3, MYSQLI_BOTH)){
        echo "<option value=" . $r3['schulname'] . ">" .$r3['schulname'] . "</option>";
      }

     echo "</select>";
   } ?><br /><br />

      </div>
    </div>
```

With this code everything is displayed and everything is working as it should. Now if a user selects something from the dropdown list, not all data are saved inside the database.

Here is how is save the data inside my database:

```
$schule_lehrer = mysqli_real_escape_string ($connect, $_POST['schule-lehrer']);
$query = "INSERT INTO teacher (schule) VALUES ('schule_lehrer')";
```

For example I have the following entries inside my dropdown field:

SRG Traumschule,
AHS Bergschule,
AHS Testschule,

If a user selects "SRG Traumschule" for example and submits the form, inside my database for the user I only see "SRG" instead of "SRG Traumschule" or if a user selects "AHS Testschule" I only see inside the database "Test". 
See here: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0c8572u7c8

Can someone help me and tell me why this issue appears? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you were not enclosing your `option` elements `value` attribute

```
echo "<option value=" . $r3['schulname'] . ">" .$r3['schulname'] . "</option>";
                   ^^                       ^^
```

needs to be

```
echo "<option value='" . $r3['schulname'] . "'>" .$r3['schulname'] . "</option>";
                    ^^                       ^^
```

Your code will work unless until you don't have `space` within your values